# Convert an expression with func with two parameters to a func with one parameter

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Inside a loop I need to convert `Expression<Func<To, From, bool>>` to `Expression<To, bool>`.

```
public static void UpdateCollection<TFrom, TTo>(IEnumerable<TFrom> from, IList<TTo> to, Expression<Func<TTo, TFrom, bool>> expression)
    where TFrom : class, IProjection<TTo, TFrom>, new()
    where TTo : class, new()
  {
    var toQueryable = to.AsQueryable();
    foreach (var item in from)
    {
        Expression<Func<TTo, bool>> predicate = // simplify expression
        var existing = toQueryable.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if (existing != null)
            TFrom.Update(item, existing);
        else
            to.Add(TFrom.Project(item));
    }
  }

UpdateCollection(from, to, (to, from) => to.Name == from.FirstName && to.LastName == from.SurName);
```

I need it to replace the second parameter with values from the `item` inside the loop.
So, given this set of values for from:

```
| FirstName | SurName |
| --------- | ------- |
| John      | Doe     |
| Bob       | Jones   |
| Mary      | Smith   |
```

The first time throw the loop `predicate` will look like this:

```
to => to.FirstName == "John" && to.LastName == "Doe"
```

And so on.
I know I've done this before, but it's eluding me now.

Comment: A brute-force approach might be to rebuild the expression tree and replace all occurrences of the parameter with your value. This would probably require to handle all possible node types.